# Using user defined method to print line to console in java

Tags: java

I have simple program like this

```
class println 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  System.out.println("Hello World!");
 }
}
```

But i dont want to use `System.out.println` to print..i want to use my own user defined method to print the data.

Comment: Why you don't want to use System.out.println?

Comment: println is a terrible class name. Class names should start with an upper-case character and should describe what the class is about.

Comment: er... so what's the question here?  Just change the code to call your method instead!

Comment: What is the problem. If you don't want to use println(), don't! It is your program...

Comment: println is not a classname :(

Answer (score 4):

Bear in mind that Java code runs in the JVM, and the JVM only communicates to the outside world in a few specified ways.  So if you want to print to a console, you will need to call a method that somehow (after JNI, etc.) gets mapped to an IO operation on your actual OS.  Unless you plan on building a new OS-level IO operation (in which case you can't write it in Java anyway), your best bet is to use an existing class that already knows how to talk to the outside world.

As it happens, the `java.io.PrintStream` class knows how to write to an OS level file stream, and the OS provides a file stream for the console (`stdout`).  (Technically, `PrintStream` only knows how to write to an `OutputStream`, and `OutputStream` knows how to write to an OS level file stream, but I don't want to get bogged down in details.)  Java provides an instance of `PrintStream` already attached to your process's standard output stream; that `PrintStream` object can be referenced as the `out` property of the `java.lang.System` object.  Given that `PrintStream` has methods like `println()`, you can write:

```
java.lang.System.out.println("Hello, world!");
```

Since you always get `java.lang.*` imported by default, you can shorten that to:

```
System.out.println("Hello, world!");
```

Alternatively, you can assign the `PrintStream` instance to a local variable:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintStream p = System.out;
        p.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

What does your "user defined method to print" do that the `println()` method of `PrintStream` objects doesn't?  If you're interested in **formatting** the output, then you need to format it as a `String` **before** you call the `println()` method.  As a convenience, you can wrap up the formatting and actual printing in a single helper method.  Is this what you're actually looking for?

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess here: is this for logging purposes? I'd guess that a good proportion of people who want to write to the console are doing so for logging purposes and that a very high proportion of those people don't want to use System.out.println() so that they can have greater control of switching that particular form of logging on and off.

If my guess is correct, might I suggest looking into a logging framework like [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) or [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/)/[Logbac](http://logback.qos.ch/)k? You'll get console appenders and whatever degree of control you need.

Answer (score 1):

`System` is a `final class` from the `java.lang` package.
`out` is a class variable of type `PrintStream` declared in the `System` class.
`println` is a method of the `PrintStream` class.

So, if you want to overwrite `prinln` method, define your own method instead and pass the `Printstrem` object in that method.

**Method 2:**
Create your own `PrintStream` - e.g. `public class YourPrintStream extends PrinterStream`.
Override the `print(String s)` method and change the string there any way you like. Then call `super.print(s));`
Call `System.setOut(new YourPrintStream())` 
Then everytime `System.out.println` is called, the passed string will be under your control before going into the actual stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
class HelloWorld 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    myPrint("Hello World!");
  }

  public static void myPrint(String message) {
    System.out.print(message + "\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: but i dont want to use "System.out.println" at all

Comment: How do you want to print in the console then? What do you have against it?

Comment: There, Gourav, fixed it for you, no more "System.out.println". But until you can specify WHY you want to avoid that, we can play this crazy nit-picking game all day long.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println` is a call of the method `println` of the static instance `out` (class `PrintStream`) of the class `System`.

In Java, there is no way to rename existing methods or instance fields (i.e. you can't change the name of `println` or `out` to anything else) and `System.out` is the only way to get at the value of `out` (which connects you to the console).

So there is no way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to intercept all content going to `System.out.println()`. You can do the following:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(buffer);
System.setOut(printStream);

System.out.println("Hello!");

String whatWasPrinted = new String(buffer.getBytes());
```

Using techniques like this, you can supply a custom stream with custom "printing" code to do what you need.